# How to access the QListWidget or QListWidgetItem from a QAbstractItemDelegate

Tags: qt, list, delegates, paint, qlistwidget

Is this even possible in Qt? I have a QListWidget setup with a delegate for specific painting, and I'm attempting to have the delegate paint differently based on variables in my QListWidget's parent. I figure I can rig something up as long as I have a pointer to either, but I need to somehow get them while in the delegate's paint().

I've tried the "hack" to store a pointer in a QVariant, but it doesn't seem to be working, and I'd rather not take this approach. If I could get to the pointer to item the delegate represents, and just call item->listWidget(), this would be perfect, but it doesn't seem possible while inside the delegate.

Is there any workaround to accomplish this?

Also, just because.. sample of trying to get the void* trick to work - if this is the only way to do this, perhaps someone may see what I have wrong in it.

```
//Parent of QListWidget
....
QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem();
....
QVariant v = qVariantFromValue((void *) pStitchSymbolCustom);
item->setData(Qt::UserRole + 6, v);
....


//Implemented QAbstractItemDelegate
....
MyClass* p_pointer = 
    (MyClass*)(index.data(Qt::UserRole + 6).value<void *>());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if i understood your question correctly, but if you want to access the QListWidget wich contains your delegate, then i think, that the easiest way is to set the parent of the delegate as the listwidget, and then get the listwidget at any point of the delegate:

```
QAbstractItemDelegate * delegate = new MyItemDelegate(myListWidget);

myListWidget.setItemDelegate(delegate);
```

and then in the delegate code:

```
QListWidget * listWidget = qobject_cast<QListWidget*>(parent());

//You can do whatever you want your list here
```

If your object tree is deep, and you want the code to be generic and not care about where the desired parent is, you should ascend the tree automatically:

```
QListWidget * listWidget = 0;
QObject * object = parent();
while (object && ! listWidget) {
    // qobject_cast will succeed once the parent of the correct type is reached
    listWidget = qobject_cast<QListWidget*>(object);
    object = object->parent();
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, duh. I should probably stop ignoring setting the parent for my reimplemented classes. Thanks.

Comment: You are wellcome. It's really useful to set the parent, and you can do this with everything, what inherits from QObject :)

Comment: Just verified it works - takes about 8 parent() calls to get what I want since it's embedded in a few spliters, but works perfectly :)

And after missing something like that, that's the cue to take a break!

Comment: You will want to ascend up the object tree automatically and stop once you reach the class you want. See my edit.